# SQL: List the employees who report to those employees who report to (____)

Tags: sql

from this table..
[Employees Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdzO6.jpg)

Question: List the employees who report to those employees who report to Diane Murphy. Use the CONCAT function to combine the employee's first name and last name into a single field for reporting.

My non-working query..

```
SELECT employeeNumber, CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName), reportsTo
FROM Employees 
WHERE reportsto= 1002 
AND WHERE (SELECT CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName), reportsTo
             FROM employees
             WHERE reportsTo= 1056 AND 1076);
```

I am really confused by this question to be honest.

1002= Diane Murphy

1056= Mary Patterson

1076= Jeff Firrelli

Based on my understanding, im trying to query this based on a hierarchal system. 
I know that both Mary and Jeff report to Diane Murphy and i can look at the table to see who reports to Mary and Jeff, but im lost exactly i go about querying this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Do a recursive query, or hard code some number of joins to handle a hierarchy of a fixed depth.  The latter option is mostly database independent, the former one is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT A.employeeNumber, CONCAT(A.firstName, ' ', A.lastName), A.reportsTo
FROM Employees A 
INNER JOIN Employees B ON A.reportsTo = B.employeeNumber
WHERE B.reportsto = 1002
```

Alias `B` and condition will fetch employees reports to `1002` & thus you will get employees who reports to `1056` & `1076`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
select e1.employeeNumber, CONCAT(e1.firstName, ' ', e1.lastName), e1.reportsTo
from Employees as e1 
inner join Employees as e2 on e1.reportsTo = e2.employeeNumber
where e2.reportsTo = 1002
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much! that was perfect. You're a life saver! lol